# How to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a UITextfield; however, I can't seem to get it to behave properly.  What I want is to override the default long press behavior (the magnifying glass and the option to "paste"), but also keep the ability to tap in the textfield in order to type in it. With the code below, it still brings up the magnifying glass and even though it enters the `textFieldLongPressed` method, it never has the correct state. Any ideas?

```
- (void) addLongPressRecognizer: (UIView *) view
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldLongPressed:)];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [view addGestureRecognizer: gestureRecognizer];
    self.myGestureReconginzer = gestureRecognizer;
}

- (void) textFieldLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender 
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
        [self.delegate textFieldLongPressed:self];
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if(gestureRecognizer == self.myGestureReconginzer)
    {
        //I've tried it with and without the following line
     // [self textFieldLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer];
        return YES;
    }
    else if([gestureRecognizer class] == [UILongPressGestureRecognizer class])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding something like this to your UITextField subclass:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:)) 
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

This should disable the option to paste.